# Pourquoi on dit "liberté d'expression" et non "liberté de l'expression"?

Tags: articles, noms

Je voudrais poser une question quant à l'utilisation de l'article défini après *de* et quand on ne l'utilise pas.

En effet, je voudrais savoir pourquoi on dit « ministère de ***la*** santé » et non « ministère ***de*** santé » étant donné que c'est le ministère qui est chargé de ce domaine ? Comme on dit « prof ***de*** français » et non « prof ***du*** français. »

D'ailleurs, ce qui me rend le plus perplexe, c'est pourquoi dit-on « la notion de liberté » et non pas « la notion de la liberté » vu que la liberté est une notion qui nécessite un article défini en général ?

Comment: Bonjour :) D'abord, le contexte est important. Par exemple, dans _Je parle de la liberté de **l**'expression du roi Jean_ on souligne qu'il s'agit de l'expression du roi Jean. Mon exemple est assez maladroit, mais je ne trouve pas un meilleur exemple. Puis, peut-être que ce lien sera utile : [Les articles](http://french.chass.utoronto.ca/fre180/Articles.html) _On n'utilise pas d'article quand un nom est le complément qui détermine un autre nom : un laboratoire **de** langue, un jour **de** pluie_. "De français" joue un rôle d'adjectif dans "prof de français".

Comment: Oui, merci beaucoup pour votre réponse bien compréhensive :) Je le comprends mieux maintenant.